# In Python, how to take in a string text, and returns a list which contains lists of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, text

This function takes in a string text, and returns a list which contains lists of strings, one list for each sentence in the string text.

Sentences are separated by one of the strings **".", "?", or "!".** We ignore the possibility of other punctuation separating sentences. so 'Mr.X' will turn to 2 sentences, and 'don't' will be two words.

For example, the text is

```
Hello, Jack.  How is it going?  Not bad; pretty good, actually...  Very very
good, in fact.
```

And the function returns:

> ```
>  ['hello', 'jack'],
>  ['how', 'is', 'it', 'going'],
>  ['not', 'bad', 'pretty', 'good', 'actually'],
>  ['very', 'very', 'good', 'in', 'fact']]
> ```

The most confusing part is how to make the function detect the characters , . ! ?  and how to make it a list of lists contains words in each sentence.
Thank you.

Comment: `re.split("[.?!]",all_text)` should get you the first part ,`re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",some_text)` would get you all the alpha words (letters only) in a block of text

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very much like a homework problem to me, so I'll provide general tips instead of exact code.

a string has the split(char) function on it.  You can use this to split your string based on a specific character.  However, you will have to use a loop and perform the split multiple times.

You could also use a regular expression to find matches (that would be a better solution.)  That would let you find all matches at once.  Then you would iterate over the matches and spit them based on spaces, while stripping out punctuation.

Edit: Here's an example of a regular expression you could use to get sentence groups all at once:

```
\s*([^.?!]+)\s*
```

The \s* surrounding the parenthesis causes any extra spaces to be removed from the result, and the parenthesis are a capture group. You can use re.findall() to get a list of all captured results, and then you can loop over these items and use re.split() and some conditional logic to append all the words to a new list.

Let me know how you get along with that, and if you have any other questions please provide us the code you have so far.

Comment: what does match mean here? I don't need a specific solution, but just a detailed explanation, Thank you!

Comment: Try out regexhero.net or some other regular expression tool.  The problem with the "empty lines" that the other user was having was due to leaving out a +, which specifies a capture group of at least one item.

Comment: @humberthumbert116, I noticed that you didn't choose an accepted answer.  If you feel my answer solved your issue, please accept it so I can get the rep for it.  Otherwise, let me know if you have any other questions I can help with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `re.split()` :

```
>>> s="Hello, Jack.  How is it going?  Not bad; pretty good, actually...  Very very good, in fact."
>>> import re
>>> [re.split(r'\W',i) for i in re.split(r'\.|\?|\!',s) if len(i)]
```

and for remove empty indices you can do this :

```
>>> [[x for x in i if len(x)]for i in my_s]
[['Hello', 'Jack'], ['How', 'is', 'it', 'going'], ['Not', 'bad', 'pretty', 'good', 'actually'], ['Very', 'very', 'good', 'in', 'fact']]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `[.?!]` ? And also this returns empty strings .

Comment: `[.?!]` can be used too, about empty string i will edit the answer !