# split sentences with multiple characters and join them at the end of each sentence

Tags: python, string, text, replace, split

I have a text file with 1000 sentences. I splitted the sentences from **'.'** but there are also **'?'** and **'!'** available in those sentences. I need to split them as well and also join those characters at the end of those sentences.
eg: **text** = "I have a friend. I have many friends! I am very happy today.Are you happy? I wish you were."
**Output:**

```
I have a friend.
I have many friends!
I am very happy today.
Are you happy?
I wish you were.
```

The code I've tried is

```
textsentences = text.split('.')
I have tried this code.
with open("file.txt",'w') as writefile:
    for line in textsentences:
        line = line.strip()
        writefile.write("%s . \n" % line)
```

It works only for one character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how to take in a string text, and returns a list which contains lists of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783320/in-python-how-to-take-in-a-string-text-and-returns-a-list-which-contains-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The `line_start` variable is to avoid unnecessary spaces at beginning of the sentence:

```
text = "I have a friend. I have many friends! I am very happy today. Are you happy? I wish you were."
line_start = False
with open("file.txt", 'w') as writefile:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isalnum() or text[i] == ' ':
            if line_start == True and text[i] == ' ':
                line_start = False
                continue
            writefile.write(text[i])
        else:
            writefile.write(text[i] +'\n')
            line_start = True
```

Output : file.txt

```
I have a friend.
I have many friends!
I am very happy today.
Are you happy?
I wish you were.
```